# Why does Lagrange's theorem not work in this case?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, elliptic-curves

I come from the world of programming and mathematics is not that close to me, so maybe this will be a rather simple and banal question for someone, but it causes certain misunderstandings for me. The question is:

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)), Lagrange's theorem for groups says the following:

> In the mathematical field of group theory, Lagrange's theorem is a theorem that states that for any finite group G, the order (number of elements) of every subgroup of G divides the order of G.

However, in the example I'm working with, this rule doesn't apply for some reason. A group is created in the context of elliptic curves over a finite field. An example is as follows (I will post both a link and a picture):

[image: Elliptic curve]

Here's also a [link](https://andrea.corbellini.name/ecc/interactive/modk-mul.html?a=1&b=2&p=7&x=3&y=5).

As you can see, the curve $y^2=x^3+1*x+2$ $F_7$ makes a group of 9 points. Points are the following:

`(0,3)` `(0,4)` `(1,2)` `(1,5)` `(3,2)` `(3,5)` `(4,0)` `(6,0)` and `(Inf, Inf)` as an identity element

Therefore, the order of the curve (group) is 9.

The problem is that when I make a subgroup of the point `(3, 5)` I get the following points:

`(0,3)` `(0,4)` `(1,2)` `(1,5)` `(3,2)` `(3,5)` `(6,0)` and `(Inf, Inf)` as an identity element

So the order of the point `(3,5)` (ie the subgroups) is 8.

This is completely confusing because it contradicts Lagrange's theorem that the order of every subgroup divides the order of the group. In this case 8 does not divide 9.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145451/discussion-between-person-and-filip).

Comment: Your curve is not elliptic, you must have $y^2=x^3+x+2$.

Comment: @NickyHekster Well, I found out after asking the question that it is not an elliptic curve because it is not a non-singular curve. Still, I'm not sure what you mean when you say "you must have $y^2=x^3+x+2$"? I mean, that is the curve I'm using, unless you're talking about `mod7`?

Comment: I think he means you have a typo: you wrote $x^2$ in your question below the picture.

Comment: @ViktorVaughn Thanks a lot, I didn't even see that I had that error. Corrected!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, your curve $E: y^2 = x^3 + x + 2$ over $\mathbb{F}_7$ is singular: its discriminant is $-1792 = -2^8 \cdot 7 \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$. The short answer to your question is that the group law can't be extended to the singular point, so your group only consists of the 8 nonsingular points of $E$.

By computing partial derivatives or noting that $x^3 + x + 2 = (x+1)(x-4)^2$ over $\mathbb{F}_7$, we see that $(4,0)$ is a singular point of $E$. (See the plot below; although this is plotted over $\mathbb{R}$, it gives an idea of what is going on.) The singular point creates a problem with the chord-tangent construction used to define the group law of an elliptic curve. This construction works for nonsingular cubic curves because every line intersects the curve in 3 points, counted with multiplicity. When doubling a point, i.e., computing $2P$, we instead take the tangent line to $E$ at $P$ and compute the inverse of the third point of intersection.

$\hspace 4cm$[image]

But at a singular point, there is no well-defined tangent line. In the case of our example, the Taylor expansion near $(4,0)$ is given by $y^2 = (x-4)^3 + 5(x-4)^2$, which has no linear term. The tangent cone at $(4,0)$ is given by the lowest order homogeneous form (of degree $2$ in this case), which is $y^2 = 5(x-4)^2$. Passing to the extension $\mathbb{F}_7(\sqrt{5})$, this is the union of the lines $y = \sqrt{5}(x-4)$ and $y = -\sqrt{5}(x-4)$, so there are two tangent lines at $(4,0)$. The fancy name for this is *non-split multiplicative reduction*, and as mentioned [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98466/how-many-points-are-there-on-an-elliptic-curve-reduced-at-a-bad-prime#comment252640_98469), the nonsingular points of the curve $E$ form a cyclic group of order $p+1=8$.

$\hspace 4cm$ [image]

The author of this elliptic curve app made an oversight in not checking that the parameters given define a nonsingular Weierstrass equation. And this leads to nonsensical output since the group law is not well-defined. For instance, taking $P = (6,0)$, $Q = (4,0)$, the app returns $P+Q = (4,0)= Q$. But this is nonsense, since subtracting $Q$ from both sides gives $P = 0$, the identity of the group law. It is true, however, that the line $y=0$ that passes through $P$ and $Q$ intersects $Q$ with multiplicity $2$.

Comment: First of all, an amazing answer and thank you very much for it. I have a couple of questions here. So [here](https://graui.de/code/elliptic2/) when you enter my curve you get a notification that the curve is not non-singular, but it still calculates all the additions in the table below the image. So the table on this site is also incorrect? Also, when the discriminant of a curve is 0, does that mean the curve is singular and there is a point on the curve that violates the group law? And the group law is a binary operation that ensures closure, associativity, "identity el." and "inverse el."?

Comment: You can see that the addition table on the site you linked does not define a group. Just as I wrote above, letting $Q = (4,0)$, then for any other point $P \neq (4,0)$, that table says that $P+Q = Q$, which implies that $P = 0$ (or $P = \infty$ in the site's notation), which is nonsense. However, if you delete the $(4,0)$ row and column from the table, you'll get a well-formed addition table that gives a cyclic group of order 8. Yes, the discriminant being 0 implies that there is a singular point. The chord-tangent law only gives defines a group structure on a nonsingular cubic curve.

Comment: Yes, by the group law I mean the binary operation defining the group structure, which must satisfy the properties you've listed.

Comment: If you'd like to read more about singular Weierstrass equations, see section 3.7 of Silverman and Tate's *Rational Points on Elliptic Curves* or section III.2 of Silverman's *The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*.

Comment: Thank you. Just one more thing. How did you draw that picture you posted in the answer. I tried to plot this curve using [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) and [this](https://www.geogebra.org/graphing) site but I didn't get the same result as you when I write $y^2=x^3+x+2$. That might be caused by not setting mod7? I mean, it does not let me put it. Do you know what the problem is here or do you have any online tool or whatever you use to show this? I would like to try some more examples.

Comment: Right, over $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$, the curve given by $y^2=x^3+x+2$ is nonsingular since the discriminant is $-112 \neq 0$. I instead plotted $y^2 = (x+1)(x-4)^2$ which defines the same curve as $y^2=x^3+x+2$ mod 7, but is different over $\mathbb{Q}$. [Here's the SageMath cell I used to plot the curve](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwVykEKgCAQQNF90B3c6dQIZkkrr1KYK8lSTEJvn-3eh_-axGjBSqHv3BW9sy7v0YfMSN0k0ZqwMk4wsMIX2CS2RD7jCk0VuULV9P97DO7Oj1ZCILHBh6Tp4Y09KXyiRxyo&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

Comment: Thanks, and one more thing (I promise). You said it's nonsense that when you do P+Q when Q is (4,0) to get (4,0). It makes perfect sense and I agree with you that it is nonsense. But what "rule" of group law is broken here? The group law defines that when you use a group operation you must get some element from the group **but that element must be different from the two you use in the operation**. Am I right?

Comment: You can get the element you use in operation **ONLY**, by the group law, when one of the operands is an identity element. In our case you will always get (4,0) no matter what the second operand is and we should only get (4,0) when doing addition with (Inf,Inf)?

Comment: You can show that in a group, the identity element must be unique. Because if you had two identity elements $0$ and $0'$, then $0 = 0 + 0' = 0'$. We've shown that both $P$ and $\infty$ are identity elements, but we know that $P \neq \infty$ (they're different points in the projective plane). Or if you prefer, we've shown that $P$ is the identity from $P+Q = Q$, but then the other columns in the addition table show that it isn't the identity, which is a contradiction.

Comment: That absolutely makes sense to me. But what do you think about what I wrote? Is what I stated correct in the specific situation we are considering, but also in general? I'm talking about what I bolded.

Comment: Yes, what you wrote is true: it's basically writing in words that $P+Q = Q \implies P = 0$. This is true in any group, since the existence of inverses is part of the group axioms.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, both the main one and all these based on additional questions. You really helped me and now everything is clear to me. I hope that this additional conversation will also be helpful for someone to understand all clearly. All the best!